# Tools in the Sextante toolbox in QGIS 1.8 for interpolation?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, kriging, sextante, spline

What tools in the Sextante toolbox in QGIS 1.8 can be used for interpolation (kriging and spline)?

I have looked at every single one and could not figure it out.

Comment: Although having a fairly descriptive title i would suggest you edit your question in a way that we know what you want to do.

Comment: e.g. SAGA's ordinary kriging http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27969/how-to-perform-ordinary-kriging-in-saga-via-qgis-sextante-plug-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considered using SAGA as SEXTANTE provider?

[image]

Comment: Does that require me to download a new program? I have not heard of SAGA.

Comment: Yes it does, but it is fairly simple and i really recommend it as it adds over 239 new geoalgorithms, which are really powerful. Download the zip from here (http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html ), unzip it somewhere on your drive and specify the directory in your SEXTANTE options (providers -> SAGA). You can use all the SAGA tools inside of QGIS, so no need to learn another GIS program (which is very good and fast by the way)

Comment: Thank you. A classmate also advised that I can go into the options and then click active for SAGA and it brings up all the tools. Is this different than downloading it.