# Error when kriging in SAGA: grid file could not be opened

Tags: qgis, error, interpolation, saga, kriging

I have a point and a polygon vector shape ([shapes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ryevi5ifzmuk92/TMP.zip)) which I want to interpolate by using the saga tool "Ordinary Kriging". I always get the following error message:

> Oooops! The following output layers could not be open
>
> Grid: C:\Temp\processing\cba78634d19046f9bd0fa87f1156dac2\USERGRID.tif
> The above files could not be opened, which probably indicates that they were not correctly produced by the executed algorithm
>
> Checking the log information might help you see why those layers were not created as expected
>
> This algorithm requires SAGA to be run. A test to check if SAGA is correctly installed and configured in your system has been performed, with the following result:
> SAGA seems to be correctly installed and configured

This is the log:

```
Algorithm Ordinary kriging starting...
geostatistics_kriging "Ordinary Kriging" -POINTS "C:\Tempordner_GIS\Huen_EK\2013_wgs.shp" -ZFIELD "ertrag" -TARGET 0 -TQUALITY 0 -BLOCK -DBLOCK 100 -VAR_MAXDIST -1 -VAR_NCLASSES 100 -VAR_NSKIP 1 -VAR_MODEL "a + b * x" -SEARCH_RANGE 0 -SEARCH_RADIUS 1000 -SEARCH_POINTS_ALL 0 -SEARCH_POINTS_MIN 4 -SEARCH_POINTS_MAX 20 -SEARCH_DIRECTION 0 -USER_BVARIANCE -USER_XMIN 25.6905001604 -USER_XMAX -4.3067898396 -USER_YMIN 67.0762900341 -USER_YMAX 37.0805900341 -USER_SIZE 30 -USER_FIT 0 -USER_GRID "C:\Temp\processing\cba78634d19046f9bd0fa87f1156dac2\USERGRID.tif.sgrd" -USER_VARIANCE "C:\Temp\processing\dc7df2d6b83443b2be2154e30d0d9c8b\USERVARIANCE.tif.sgrd"
io_gdal 1 -GRIDS "C:\Temp\processing\cba78634d19046f9bd0fa87f1156dac2\USERGRID.tif.sgrd" -FORMAT 4 -TYPE 0 -FILE "C:\Temp\processing\cba78634d19046f9bd0fa87f1156dac2\USERGRID.tif"
io_gdal 1 -GRIDS "C:\Temp\processing\dc7df2d6b83443b2be2154e30d0d9c8b\USERVARIANCE.tif.sgrd" -FORMAT 4 -TYPE 0 -FILE "C:\Temp\processing\dc7df2d6b83443b2be2154e30d0d9c8b\USERVARIANCE.tif"

C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin>set SAGA=C:\Program Files (x86)\saga_2.1.0\

C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:\Program Files (x86)\saga_2.1.0\\modules

C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin>PATH=PATH;C:\Program Files (x86)\saga_2.1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\saga_2.1.0\\modules

C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin>saga_cmd geostatistics_kriging "Ordinary Kriging" -POINTS "C:\Tempordner_GIS\Huen_EK\2013_wgs.shp" -ZFIELD "ertrag" -TARGET 0 -TQUALITY 0 -BLOCK -DBLOCK 100 -VAR_MAXDIST -1 -VAR_NCLASSES 100 -VAR_NSKIP 1 -VAR_MODEL "a + b * x" -SEARCH_RANGE 0 -SEARCH_RADIUS 1000 -SEARCH_POINTS_ALL 0 -SEARCH_POINTS_MIN 4 -SEARCH_POINTS_MAX 20 -SEARCH_DIRECTION 0 -USER_BVARIANCE -USER_XMIN 25.6905001604 -USER_XMAX -4.3067898396 -USER_YMIN 67.0762900341 -USER_YMAX 37.0805900341 -USER_SIZE 30 -USER_FIT 0 -USER_GRID "C:\Temp\processing\cba78634d19046f9bd0fa87f1156dac2\USERGRID.tif.sgrd" -USER_VARIANCE "C:\Temp\processing\dc7df2d6b83443b2be2154e30d0d9c8b\USERVARIANCE.tif.sgrd"
Unknown option 'POINTS'
Usage: saga_cmd [-GRID ] [-VARIANCE ] -SHAPES [-FIELD ] [-BVARIANCE] [-TARGET ] [-MODEL ] [-BLOCK] [-DBLOCK ] [-BLOG] [-NUGGET ] [-SILL ] [-RANGE ] [-LIN_B ] [-EXP_B ] [-POW_A ] [-POW_B ] [-MAXRADIUS ] [-NPOINTS_MIN ] [-NPOINTS_MAX ] [-USER_CELL_SIZE ] [-USER_FIT_EXTENT] [-USER_X_EXTENT_MIN ] [-USER_X_EXTENT_MAX ] [-USER_Y_EXTENT_MIN ] [-USER_Y_EXTENT_MAX ] [-SYSTEM_SYSTEM_NX ] [-SYSTEM_SYSTEM_NY ] [-SYSTEM_SYSTEM_X ] [-SYSTEM_SYSTEM_Y ] [-SYSTEM_SYSTEM_D ] [-GRID_GRID ] [-GRID_VARIANCE ]
-GRID: Grid
Data Object (optional output)
-VARIANCE: Variance
Data Object (optional output)
-SHAPES: Points
Shapes (input)
-FIELD: Attribute
Table field
-BVARIANCE Create Variance Grid
Boolean
-TARGET: Target Grid
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] user defined
[1] grid system
[2] grid
-MODEL: Variogram Model
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] Spherical Model
[1] Exponential Model
[2] Gaussian Model
[3] Linear Regression
[4] Exponential Regression
[5] Power Function Regression
-BLOCK Block Kriging

Boolean
-DBLOCK: Block Size
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
-BLOG Logarithmic Transformation
Boolean
-NUGGET: Nugget
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
-SILL: Sill
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
-RANGE: Range
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
-LIN_B: Linear Regression
Floating point
-EXP_B: Exponential Regression
Floating point
-POW_A: Power Function - A
Floating point
-POW_B: Power Function - B
Floating point
-MAXRADIUS: Maximum Search Radius (map units)
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
-NPOINTS_MIN: Min./Max. Number of m_Points
Value range
-NPOINTS_MAX: Min./Max. Number of m_Points
Value range
-USER_CELL_SIZE: Grid Size
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
-USER_FIT_EXTENT Fit Extent
Boolean
-USER_X_EXTENT_MIN: X-Extent
Value range
-USER_X_EXTENT_MAX: X-Extent
Value range
-USER_Y_EXTENT_MIN: Y-Extent
Value range
-USER_Y_EXTENT_MAX: Y-Extent
Value range
-SYSTEM_SYSTEM_NX: Grid System
Grid system
-SYSTEM_SYSTEM_NY: Grid System
Grid system
-SYSTEM_SYSTEM_X: Grid System
Grid system
-SYSTEM_SYSTEM_Y: Grid System
Grid system
-SYSTEM_SYSTEM_D: Grid System
Grid system
-GRID_GRID: Grid
Grid (input)
-GRID_VARIANCE: Variance
Grid (optional input)

 C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 1 -GRIDS "C:\Temp\processing\cba78634d19046f9bd0fa87f1156dac2\USERGRID.tif.sgrd" -FORMAT 4 -TYPE 0 -FILE "C:\Temp\processing\cba78634d19046f9bd0fa87f1156dac2\USERGRID.tif"

error: Grid file could not be opened.

error: input file [C:\Temp\processing\cba78634d19046f9bd0fa87f1156dac2\USERGRID.tif.sgrd]

error: empty input list [GRIDS]
Usage: saga_cmd -GRIDS [-FILE ] [-FORMAT ] [-TYPE ] [-OPTIONS ]
-GRIDS: Grid(s)
Grid list (input)
-FILE: File
File path
-FORMAT: Format
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 3.x)
[1] Flexible Image Transport System
[2] Network Common Data Format
[3] Virtual Raster
[4] GeoTIFF
[5] National Imagery Transmission Format
[6] Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
[7] ELAS
[8] In Memory Raster
[9] MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
[10] PCIDSK Database File
[11] ILWIS Raster Map
[12] SGI Image File Format 1.0
[13] Leveller heightfield
[14] Terragen heightfield
[15] USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 2)
[16] ERMapper .ers Labelled
[17] Raster Matrix Format
[18] Idrisi Raster A.1
[19] Intergraph Raster
[20] Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)
[21] Portable Pixmap Format (netpbm)
[22] ENVI .hdr Labelled
[23] ESRI .hdr Labelled
[24] PCI .aux Labelled
[25] Vexcel MFF Raster
[26] Vexcel MFF2 (HKV) Raster
[27] VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
[28] Erdas .LAN/.GIS
[29] Image Data and Analysis
[30] NOAA Vertical Datum .GTX
[31] NTv2 Datum Grid Shift
[32] ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
[33] SAGA GIS Binary Grid (.sdat)
-TYPE: Data Type
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] match input data
[1] 8 bit unsigned integer
[2] 16 bit unsigned integer
[3] 16 bit signed integer
[4] 32 bit unsigned integer
[5] 32 bit signed integer
[6] 32 bit floating point
[7] 64 bit floating point
-OPTIONS: Creation Options
Text

C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 1 -GRIDS "C:\Temp\processing\dc7df2d6b83443b2be2154e30d0d9c8b\USERVARIANCE.tif.sgrd" -FORMAT 4 -TYPE 0 -FILE "C:\Temp\processing\dc7df2d6b83443b2be2154e30d0d9c8b\USERVARIANCE.tif"

error: Grid file could not be opened.

error: input file [C:\Temp\processing\dc7df2d6b83443b2be2154e30d0d9c8b\USERVARIANCE.tif.sgrd]

error: empty input list [GRIDS]
Usage: saga_cmd -GRIDS [-FILE ] [-FORMAT ] [-TYPE ] [-OPTIONS ]
-GRIDS: Grid(s)
Grid list (input)
-FILE: File
File path
-FORMAT: Format
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 3.x)
[1] Flexible Image Transport System
[2] Network Common Data Format
[3] Virtual Raster
[4] GeoTIFF
[5] National Imagery Transmission Format
[6] Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
[7] ELAS
[8] In Memory Raster
[9] MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
[10] PCIDSK Database File
[11] ILWIS Raster Map
[12] SGI Image File Format 1.0
[13] Leveller heightfield
[14] Terragen heightfield
[15] USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 2)
[16] ERMapper .ers Labelled
[17] Raster Matrix Format
[18] Idrisi Raster A.1
[19] Intergraph Raster
[20] Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)
[21] Portable Pixmap Format (netpbm)
[22] ENVI .hdr Labelled
[23] ESRI .hdr Labelled
[24] PCI .aux Labelled
[25] Vexcel MFF Raster
[26] Vexcel MFF2 (HKV) Raster
[27] VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
[28] Erdas .LAN/.GIS
[29] Image Data and Analysis
[30] NOAA Vertical Datum .GTX
[31] NTv2 Datum Grid Shift
[32] ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
[33] SAGA GIS Binary Grid (.sdat)
-TYPE: Data Type
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] match input data
[1] 8 bit unsigned integer
[2] 16 bit unsigned integer
[3] 16 bit signed integer
[4] 32 bit unsigned integer
[5] 32 bit signed integer
[6] 32 bit floating point
[7] 64 bit floating point
-OPTIONS: Creation Options
Text

C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin>exit
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm Ordinary kriging finished
```

---

I found out something...

When I checked the temp files I can find a result.tif as well as a result.sdat. QGis tries to open the tif which is obviously destroyed. I just can open the sdat file and its ok! Is that an error?

Comment: Maybe related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27969/how-to-perform-ordinary-kriging-in-saga-via-qgis-sextante-plug-in with some nice comments ;-)  And perhaps http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8877 has fixed the problem, or added some more...

Comment: I know these two links but it doesnt change the situation. Some days ago it works fine but now...?

Comment: I got the same errors. It might be necessary to change the default values in the form depending on the input data. Can you add a shapefile that definitely works?

Comment: This shape file worked before:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4y75u09nfghm3q/shape.zip

Comment: That works for me. Your first example works too, if I reproject it to DHDN4. I think that the search radius of 1000 map units will spoil the calculation when using lat/lon degrees in EPSG:4326.

Comment: The crazy thing is that other tools like shapes to grid show up the same issue. Maybe it's a problem with the windows folder security (no writing permission?)?

Comment: I usually select the output folder to something different than temp.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14210/discussion-between-pimpel-and-andre-joost)